# Recovery mode -> Kernel Panic, "purple screen of death" on default boot

Tags: boot, grub2, kernel, 19.04

Upgrading from 18.10 to 19.04 (software updater) Boot Grub 2.02 '*' (default) selection -> "purple screen of death' re-boot & selection #2: "Advanced options for Ubuntu" : "Ubuntu with Linux 5.0.0.13-generic (recovery model" --》screen shown in image
[image: kernel panic details - couldn't copy-paste]

Answer (score 0):

I did a workaround be installing Ubuntu 16.04 from a bootable USB stick I had in my computer bag's pocket.  It got me running again when none of the exploration I tried worked. More drastic than a reboot for "blue screen of death" but it got me online and working again.